# How to remove controller_name and function_name from url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite, routes

i have a url structure like

```
http://example.com/merchant/index/1-westside
```

currently i have added one line in routes.php like

```
$route['merchant/(:any)'] = "merchant/index";
```

By using this routes i am getting url like

```
http://example.com/merchant/1-westside
```

but i need the url like

```
http://example.com/1-westside
```

In short, i want to hide the controller_name also i.e "merchant" from the url. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'merchant/index/$1';
```

But beware this will affect all requests to the site so if there are other controllers you want to use you will need to create a route for them and place them before this route.

So, if you create another controller called `payments`, for example, you will need to place a route for it before this one:

```
$route['payments/(:any)'] = 'payments/index/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'merchant/index/$1';
```

This won't work correctly:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'merchant/index/$1';
$route['payments/(:any)'] = 'payments/index/$1';
```

Also, you can only do this for one controller. i.e. you can only have 1 controller and method that utilizes the "controller-less" url. If you want to use another controller method  besides `merchant/index`, you will have to use the controller name (or some identifier) in the URL for the route to understand what you want.

Comment: yes you are right i need to use any.But please tell me how can i use "multiple any" in routes. As i have 4-5 urls.I have used if else in routes but its only working for one any statement.

Comment: You can only do this for one controller/method. I updated the answer to clarify. Update your question with more details (like what are the URL's, what do you want them to look like, etc) if you want a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `$route['default_controller'] = 'merchant';`.

Comment: i have a default controller "home". This home controller loads first.If i make it "merchant" the the home page will never be loaded.

Comment: stormdrain's answer is much better.